# Telegram bot send QR code php

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I have telegram bot and my bot will send Welcome message with QR code.
QR code generated by user id. Now I have this code...

```
$botToken = "";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;


$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, TRUE);
$message = $update["message"];


$chatId = $message["chat"]["id"];
$text = $message["text"];   

if ($text == '/start') {
    $welcomemessage = 'Добро пожаловать. Сохраните полученный id и введите его в приложение I am here: ';

   file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$welcomemessage);  
   file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$chatId);    // send QR picture will be here
}
```

May be http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=a&chld= (user_id)

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: I don't know how send photo from this url http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=a&chld=

Comment: On a complete sidenote: Why are you sending QR codes to what's very likely going to be a mobile device, which would normally also be the device you use to scan a QR code in the world. If its just to share an URL or so then it's probably not worth the hassle in my opinion. But, I don't know what you are planning, so who knows. Maybe QR is integral to what you are doing. Just wanted to let you know :P

Comment: I find more simple way to realize my idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sendPhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) requires at least two parameters; first one is target *chat_id*, and for second one *photo* you have three options:

1. Pass [file_id](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) if the photo is already uploaded to telegram servers (recommended because you don't need to reupload it).
2. If the photo is uploaded somewhere else, pass the full http url and telegram will download it (max photo size is 5MB atm).
3. Post the file using multipart/form-data like you want to upload it via a browser (10MB max photo size this way).
   you can try this:

   `$website."/sendPhoto?chat_id=".$chatId."&photo=".$yourPhotoURL`

beware according to [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files) :

> When sending by URL the target file must have the correct MIME type (e.g., audio/mpeg for sendAudio, etc.).

Comment: So, Thanks, BUT I have some problems. When I push             file_get_contents($website."/sendPhoto?chat_id=".$chatId."&photo=".$yourPhotoURL);  from this site   http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=itmathrepetitor     Telegram don't send photo

Comment: @AndreySergeev yes,its true,i have no idea why its not working,never seen this problem with any URL before,the API times out !,its weird,maybe its blocked from telegram side ...?